# Issue with UITableViewCell and checking clicks

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So I am using a uitableview to display multiple images and labels.  I want to be able to check the text of the label of the cell that is clicked so that I can identify which one is clicked.

The reason I do this is because I want to do a different action for one cell being clicked, and a different action for another.

This is how I populate my cells (from a prototype cell) With the cell defenition from a class called CustomCell

```
//tableview datasource delegate methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return cellIconNames.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cellIconName = [cellIconNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSString *cellIconImageName = [[self cellIconImages] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.rightLabel.text = [cellIconNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.carrierImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIconImageName];
cell.urlString = [cellIconNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

The way I am checking to see which one is clicked is by doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];

if ([cell.urlString isEqualToString:@"Aetna"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.aetna.com"]];
}else if([cell.urlString isEqualToString:nil]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
}
NSLog(@"cell was clicked %@", cell);
}
```

When i click a cell, nothing happens.  Now i have made that NSLOG so that i can make sure the cells are being read correctly which they are.

I also have commented out my testing line of code, I had the if else statment commented out and just ran the one commented line of code, and nothing happens.

Please help me, i have no idea what is going wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the URL method into the string (e.g. http://).

Comment: Such a simple answer I never considered it, why did this change anything? out of curiosity  (it worked)

Comment: It makes sense when you think about the fact that you can invent your own URL methods and register them to launch other programs using essentially the same UIApplication call you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Just double-checking that you've both added your UITableViewController as a UITableViewDelegate and have either programatically or in Interface Builder have wired the delegate back to your controller?

Comment: self.carrierTableView.delegate = self;
    self.carrierTableView.dataSource =self;

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you shouldn't be looking at the cell at all. You should look at the data in your data model. Just like you did in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, get the data for the **indexPath**. Then do the appropriate check against the data.

Comment: What do you mean by this? I need to get the text of the label that is in that specific cell that was selected so that I can check which one it was

Comment: @Maddy Or are you saying that i can check which is was by index of the array of cells in the tableview? If this is the case how would i do that

Comment: I already said what to do. Use the indexPath exactly like you do in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to get the data. Once you have the data, you can do whatever it is that you need to do with the data. The cell is just a view. Your data source has the actual data you should be working with.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just a bit of a noob when it comes to this i guess :/ I don't know how to check the text of the label in that specific cell.  Do I create a new cell with like CustomCell *cell = [carrierTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: No, you don't create another cell. I saying that you completely ignore the cell. Just look at the data. It's not appropriate to extract data from a view. A view displays data. Use your data model for the data. As a new developer, you should read up on MVC - Model, View, Controller. It's very important in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know why u are not understanding it easily just use indexpath.row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and u will simply get the desired cell.